# Problemas con una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Buenos días. Estoy haciendo una tabla en donde se agregan filas y estas se pueda editar. Tenía un problema anterior el cual consistía en que solo editaba el encabezado, ya arregle ese problema pero se generó otro: **solo me edita la primera fila** pero la segunda fila y posteriores no las edita. No se por qué ocurre este problema; les muestro mi programa para que me puedan entender mejor:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#bt_add').click(function() {
    var check = [];
    $("#tabla").find('.selected').find('td').each(function(){
      if($.trim($(this).text()) === "")
        check.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    if(check.length === 0)
      agregar();
    else
      alert('Registre los Datos de la Fila ');
  });
 
   $('#bt_del').click(function() {
     eliminar();
   });

   $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
     eliminarTodasFilas();

   });


 });
 var cont = 0;
 var id_fila_selected = [];

 function agregar() {
   cont++;
   var fila =

     '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + 'onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>&nbsp;</td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"  placeholder="Ingresar nombre"></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="area"  placeholder="Ingresar area"></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"  placeholder="Ingresar puesto"></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="email"  placeholder="Ingresar email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';


   $('#tabla').append(fila);
   reordenar();
 }

 function addToTable(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
     const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
     const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
     const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
     [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
       if (i === 0) { td.textContent = i + 1; }
       else { td.innerHTML = values[i - 1]; }
     });
     reordenar();
   }
 }

 function seleccionar(id_fila) {
   if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
     $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
   
     var existe_el_id = id_fila_selected.indexOf(id_fila); 
     id_fila_selected.splice(existe_el_id, 1);
   } else {
     $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
    
     id_fila_selected.push(id_fila); 
   }
  
 }

 function eliminar() {

   for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
     $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
   }
   reordenar();
 }

 function reordenar() {
   var num = 1;
   $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
     $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
     num++;
   });
 }

 function eliminarTodasFilas() {
   $('#tabla tr.selected').each(function() {
     $(this).remove();
   });
 }
 
 $(function () {        
    $("td").on("dblclick",function () {     
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        $(this).children().first().focus();
        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                }
            });
        $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
            $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
}

.selected {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected:hover {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}

.seleccionada {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <div id="content">
      <h1> Tabla de Ejemplo </h1>
      <br>
   <div align="center" style="width:416px;" >
      <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
   <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
      <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar todo</button>
    </div>
      <table id="tabla" style= "position:absolute;top:150px;left:75px" class="table table-bordered">
         
      <thead style="background-color:powderblue;">
  
    
  <tr>
   <th >Nº</th>
   <th>NOMBRE</th>
   <th>AREA</th>
   <th>PUESTO</th>
   <th>EMAIL</th>
 
   </tr>
     
    <tr id=fila'+cont+' onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="nombre"  placeholder="Ingresar nombre"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="area"  placeholder="Ingresar area"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="puesto"  placeholder="Ingresar puesto"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="email"  placeholder="Ingresar email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>
    
      </thead>
         </table>
         </div>


</body>
```

Comment: @GustavoGarcia me funciono, le agradezco por su atención y por resolver mi problema, ya le di palomita a su respuesta y  un punto. 
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema pasa porque cuando añades los escuchadores para las celdas estos se aplican **solo a las celdas que existen en ese momento** en el DOM. Cuando tu agregas nuevas filas, agregas esas filas bajo demanda, por ende, estas filas no tienen ningún listener asociado porque recién han sido creadas y agregadas al DOM.

Haz uso de *event delegation* para que de esta manera, el listener sea escuchado en la tabla y se delege a las celdas.

**Ejemplo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bt_add').click(function() {
    var check = [];
    $("#tabla").find('.selected').find('td').each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).text()) === "")
        check.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    if (check.length === 0)
      agregar();
    else
      alert('Registre los Datos de la Fila ');
  });

  $('#bt_del').click(function() {
    eliminar();
  });

  $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
    eliminarTodasFilas();

  });


});
var cont = 0;
var id_fila_selected = [];

function agregar() {
  cont++;
  var fila =

    '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + 'onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>&nbsp;</td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"  placeholder="Ingresar nombre"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="area"  placeholder="Ingresar area"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"  placeholder="Ingresar puesto"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="email"  placeholder="Ingresar email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';


  $('#tabla').append(fila);
  reordenar();
}

function addToTable(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
    const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
    const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        td.textContent = i + 1;
      } else {
        td.innerHTML = values[i - 1];
      }
    });
    reordenar();
  }
}

function seleccionar(id_fila) {
  if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
    $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');

    var existe_el_id = id_fila_selected.indexOf(id_fila);
    id_fila_selected.splice(existe_el_id, 1);
  } else {
    $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');

    id_fila_selected.push(id_fila);
  }

}

function eliminar() {

  for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
    $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
  }
  reordenar();
}

function reordenar() {
  var num = 1;
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
    num++;
  });
}

function eliminarTodasFilas() {
  $('#tabla tr.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}

$(function() {
  $("table").on("dblclick", "td", function() {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();
    $(this).children().first().keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        var newContent = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
      }
    });
    $(this).children().first().blur(function() {
      $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
      $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
}

.selected {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected:hover {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}

.seleccionada {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h1> Tabla de Ejemplo </h1>
    <br>
    <div align="center" style="width:416px;">
      <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
      <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar todo</button>
    </div>
    <table id="tabla" style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:75px" class="table table-bordered">

      <thead style="background-color:powderblue;">


        <tr>
          <th>Nº</th>
          <th>NOMBRE</th>
          <th>AREA</th>
          <th>PUESTO</th>
          <th>EMAIL</th>

        </tr>

               </thead>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>
```